# What if $\omega =0$, which is the frequency of the perturbation term?

Tags: classical-mechanics, perturbation-theory, stability

In analytic mechanics, when we found a equilibrium position of the system, to determine the stability of that configuration, we apply $q \to q_0 + \epsilon \eta$ with $|\eta| \ll 1$ s.t $q_0$ is the equilibrium condition.

After plugging $q$ to EoM, for example, if we get a solution for $\eta$ in the form 
$$\ddot \eta + \omega \eta = 0,$$
depending on the sign of $\omega$, we can argue whether the system is stable around $q_0$ or not.

**Question:**

However, what if $\omega =0$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $\omega =0$ or $\omega = 0 + O(\eta)$?

Comment: In here, I'm only considering first order perturbation, but if the answer is going to chance, I would like to hear both.

Comment: The general case will be that the stability of the point depends on the next order in perturbation theory.

Comment: @mmeent Well, that is logical; what about in the linear case ?

Comment: The question of stability doesn't make sense in the "linear" case, because stability refers only to points that are maxima and minima of potential. That is, you need an equilibrium before you can have a stable or unstable equilibrium. Zero frequency implies a linear potential, which has no extrema. Thus the "zero frequency" case is ambiguous, and you need more info. The substitution you make assumes a non-linear potential, by the way.

Comment: @flevinBombastus the frequency does not belong to the equilibrium, it belongs to the perturbation, i.e when $\epsilon = 0$, $q_0$ is already and equilibrium.

Comment: If there is an equilibrium, then the assumption that $q=q_0+\epsilon \eta$ implies that an object will stay close to that equilibrium. If you then obtain an equation that says $\ddot{\eta}=0$, then at most your particle is moving with constant velocity. For this to be true, there must not have been an equilibrium in the potential to begin with. The frequency "belongs" to the equilibrium insofar as you approximate the equilibrium in order to get a frequency of motion; that is, it is specific to the shape of the potential.

Comment: @flevinBombastus I don't want to be rude, so don't get me wrong, but do you even know what is a perturbation ? Have you done any ? because it looks like we are not on the same foot.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing about you, my friend. A more constructive comment would be to point out exactly where you disagree with me so I can provide a better explanation. As it is, I don't see where your misunderstanding is.

Comment: @flevinBombastus The whole point of a perturbation to test whether if you start around the equilibrium point, will you stay around it, so $q = q_0 + \epsilon \eta$ does not imply directly that "an object will stay close to that equilibrium"; if it was, there would no point in doing perturbation in the first place.

Comment: @flevinBombastus Moreover, $\ddot \eta$ does not contradict with the fact that $q_0$ is an equilibrium; if you have **an argument** why that should be the case, please share.

Comment: @flevinBombastus note also that $\omega$ is the frequency of the perturbation solution, if that perturbation solution if periodic.

Comment: I disagree with your first comment. You said, let $q \leftarrow q_0 + \epsilon\eta,$" with $|\eta| \ll 1$. You specified the perturbation will be small. Right there. You assumed right there that the object would stay close to equilibrium. The reason you do the perturbation is to see what the motion looks like near this point. But if you get $\omega=0$, then it moves linearly around that point, which is to say it will eventually get away from that point in a way you don't understand without going to higher orders in the perturbation theory. Thus the "linear case" isn't enough information.

Comment: Also, I said the very specific case $\ddot{\eta}=0$ suggests you don't have an equilibrium. An equilibrium is defined by an extremum, which requires the first derivative of the potential to be zero and the second derivative to be nonzero. If you get $\omega=0$, then the particle moves linearly to this order in your perturbation, which it wouldn't do if the second derivative were nonzero. Therefore there is not an equilibrium.

Comment: @flevinBombastus Consider a ball on top of another ball which is bigger than the first one; if the small one is right at the top, that is an equilibrium configuration for that ball, but if you perturb it around that point, even slightly, the ball will stay around that equilibrium potential; this example is a clear violation of your first statement.

Comment: @flevinBombastus Secondly, what if the external forces acting on the system are not derivable from a potential, then you don't have a potential energy, does this mean there cannot be any equilibrium configuration for the system since you say  an equilibrium point is an extremum of potential ?; this is the violation of your second claim.

Comment: First, I think you have a typo: the ball will *not* stay around the equilibrium after you perturb it. Does $\ddot{\eta}=0$ in that example? My expectation is that it does not. I would anticipate a negative $\omega$ (as you've defined it), implying instability. If your forces are nonconservative, an equilibrium point is at best ill-defined, because if you perturb a particle from some "observed" equilibrium, the nonconservative force shifts the equilibrium. Think of a mass on a horizontal spring attached to a block, all resting on a surface with friction; how does it act when you push it?

Comment: Note that, in your example, the potential is not only that of gravity; there is also an effect due to the presence of the larger ball. That's why the second derivative is nonzero.